# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, SFTP Connection Error

Tags: server, 22.04, sftp

I'm moving my SFTP server from Centos 7 to a new Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS install on a new host, but the software I am using uses old protocols to connect and I'm having no success getting it to work.

With default configs if I point the client to the server I initially get `no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]` in the connections logs, if I add an entry to sshd_config (I'll add them to a seperate .conf later) for `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa,ssh-dss` and `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa,ssh+dss` the error changes to `kex_protocol_error: type 30 seq 1 [preauth]` but the client still won't connect, I've then appended `KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`, still no change.

The client doesn't offer much in the way of logging, is it possible to increase the logging server side so I can see what protocols are needed. Or do I need to do more than just enable  the algorithms in the config file, I notice in the config file that `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` is commented out, enabling it made little difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried by adding the line of `HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss` to your `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: I haven’t, isn’t placing it in sshd_config the same thing?

Comment: `sshd_config` is about the server side and not the client side.  When a file that is a service type ends in `d` that usually means that it is a daemon that is listening.  In the top of the `sshd_config` file it states:  `# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.`

Comment: I tried creating ```~/.ssh/config``` and adding the entries there, no change. I've now enabled ```DEBUG3``` in ```sshd_config``` which gives me more details, the client (software running on a Windows PC) is clearly trying to use an algorithm not supported on the server (Ubuntu 22.04) but I'm unable to work out which it requires.

I've also pulled the logs from the current server which works with the software and the only obvious thing I can see is an entry for AES128-CBC but enabling that cipher doesn't seem to allow the client to connect either.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part that you are using a Windows client and not an Ubuntu client.  That wasn't in your question, so I was getting lost here.  I can see if I can duplicate your issue with my Windows 10 installation, but I know that when the Ubuntu side is working your question might be closed here as off-topic since we don't support Windows.  I'll still take a look though.

Comment: Sorry I could have made that clearer in my question, I'm using some dictation software that has a built in FTP function, which is loaded on Windows.

I'm configuring Ubuntu as the server running SFTP, but it appears the FTP client is using older protocols but I'm unable to work out which, maybe it's time to break out Wireshark if I can't figure it out from the ```auth.logs``` on Ubuntu.

Comment: So I've been looking at this again this morning, using WINSCP I can connect to the server, so the config is okay.

If I try connecting the the legacy dictation software I'm getting this ```expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST [preauth]``` in the ```auth.log```

Comment: Looks like a possible answer at https://serverfault.com/questions/592059/debug1-expecting-ssh2-msg-kex-dh-gex-group but you would need to add that to the `ssh_config` file in Windows.  I am not 100% sure where that file is, since I have never messed with it in Windows.

Comment: Maybe this one might help for the ssh config file in Windows:  https://superuser.com/questions/1537763/location-of-openssh-configuration-file-on-windows

Comment: There’s no config file for me to modify, it looks like the application is hard coded with the algorithms. I’ve now pulled the debugs from the old server that’s working and think I’ve identified the algorithms being used. It’s failing on the Diffie Hellman key exchange, but nothing I try is working.

Comment: Maybe https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ssh-enable-diffie-hellman-key might be able to help on the server side to offer the Diffie Hellman key.

Comment: Thanks I’d already seen that and that’s the key I’ve enabled, I’m wondering if MTU is the issue. The loop back interface has a strange value and if I change that or eth0 neither seem to stick or are active.

Comment: So it's not related to MTU... I've tried removing diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 which either disables all DH keys or if I try to leave it out gets used anyway, I just can't win.

Think I'm just going to call it quits at this point. The best solution is simply going to be to replace the client software with some thing current that supports modern algorithms.